# PosgreSQL Function with INSERT... RETURNING gives query has no destination for result data

Tags: postgresql, function, return, plpgsql

I've seen many questions about the same error message but I could not find one with the same use case. Here is my schema below. I basically need my function to return the entire record inserted in the `base.batch` table. Note that I expect to call this function with Postgraphile later on. Cf. example of [custom mutation I have used here](https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/custom-mutations/)

```
CREATE SCHEMA base;

CREATE TABLE base.indicator_group (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    indicator_group TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    created_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

INSERT INTO base.indicator_group (indicator_group) VALUES ('test');

CREATE TABLE base.batch (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    status TEXT NOT NULL,
    created_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    indicator_group_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES base.indicator_group(id)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION base.execute_indicator_group(id integer)
RETURNS base.batch AS $$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO base.batch (status, indicator_group_id) VALUES ('Pending', 1)
    RETURNING *;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE STRICT SECURITY DEFINER;
```

I'm calling the function as below:

```
select base.execute_indicator_group(1);
```

It returns the error:

> ERROR:  query has no destination for result data CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL
>   function base.execute_indicator_group(integer) line 3 at SQL statement

Comment: Surprisingly it seems no Fiddle accepts my syntax above but it works on my PostgreSQL instance.

Comment: Instead of `RETURNING *;` would `RETURNING NEW.*;` or maybe just `RETURNING NEW` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a simple SQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION base.execute_indicator_group(id integer)
RETURNS base.batch AS $$
    INSERT INTO base.batch (status, indicator_group_id) VALUES ('Pending', 1)
    RETURNING *;
$$ LANGUAGE sql STRICT SECURITY DEFINER;
```

Use it in the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM base.execute_indicator_group(1);

 id | status  |        created_date        |        updated_date        | indicator_group_id 
----+---------+----------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------
  1 | Pending | 2018-08-06 23:43:15.076431 | 2018-08-06 23:43:15.076431 |                  1
(1 row)
```

In a plpgsql function (in case you want to additionally do something else inside the function) you need a variable:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION base.execute_indicator_group(id integer)
RETURNS base.batch AS $$
DECLARE
    result base.batch;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO base.batch (status, indicator_group_id) VALUES ('Pending', 1)
    RETURNING *
    INTO result;
    RETURN result;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE STRICT SECURITY DEFINER;
```